# how to set up ListFragment properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I try to create tabs with ListFragment in it. I've tried several different appoaches but neither of them works. I don't know how to set container for ListFragment obkect properly. 
Here is java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tabOne = actionBar.newTab().setText("ONE");
        ActionBar.Tab tabTwo = actionBar.newTab().setText("TWO");

        tabParkCinema.setTabListener(new tabListener());
        tab28Cinema.setTabListener(new tabListener());

        actionBar.addTab(tabOne);
        actionBar.addTab(tabTwo);

        }

    protected class tabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        ParkFragment firstFragment;

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()){
            case 0:
                if (firstFragment == null){
                    firstFragment = new ParkFragment();
                    System.out.println("initialized");
                    ft.add(R.id.cont, firstFragment,"FIRST");
                }
                else{
                    ft.attach(firstFragment);
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (firstFragment == null){
                    firstFragment = new ParkFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.cont,firstFragment,"SECOND");
                }
                else{
                    ft.attach(firstFragment);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };

    public class ParkFragment extends ListFragment {
        private ArrayList<Cinemas> cinema;
        private CinemasAdapter cinemaAdapter;
        private View v;
        //private ListView list;

          @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater in, ViewGroup gr, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            v = in.inflate(R.id.listing1, gr,false);
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            cinema = new Handler().handle(); 
            cinemaAdapter = new CinemasAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.movie_data_row, cinema);
            setListAdapter(cinemaAdapter);
            return gr;
          }

          @Override
          public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
              Cinemas movie = cinemaAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, More.class);
                intent.putExtra("Cinemas", movie);
                intent.putExtra("data", movie.getBitmap());

                Bundle translateBundle =
                      ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                      R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
              startActivity (intent, translateBundle);

          }
        } 
}
```

And activity_main.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/cont"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <ListView   
                android:id = "@+id/listing1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
         </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for reading, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) object.

2) Use method `beginTransaction()` on this object to create a [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) object.

3) Add fragment with the method `add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)` on the `FragmentTransaction` object.

In this method, you put a reference to the id of the container, a new `ListFragment` (or the class you have writen) and a tag (to easily get a reference to the `ListFragment` if needed).

Note that you have to change your xml layout. You can add a `FrameLayout` with an id. And then, give this id to the method `add()` of your `FragmentTransaction` object.

**EDIT**

Example of code:

> public class ContentActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>    //your action bar stuff
>
>    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
>    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
>    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.parkfragment, new ParkFragment(), "locations");
>    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
>    fragmentTransaction.commit();
>  }
>
>  public class ParkFragment extends ListFragment {
>    //your methods
>  }
>
>  protected class tabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
>    //your methods
>  } 
> }
> ```

Your xml would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parkfragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you give example of FrameLayout for ListView?

Comment: After switching to the second tab this happens :(
http://s018.radikal.ru/i528/1303/0d/8eeb9e964cab.jpg

Comment: Use the replace() method of FragmentTransaction instead of the add() method. Otherwise you will have two fragments overlapping.